# How to use Modsec rules to certain page?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

i want to block proxy(x-forwarded) ip certain page(wp-comments-post.php) using Apache Mod_security.

**my current mod_security rule:**

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS_NAMES "^x-forwarded-for" "log,deny,id:48,status:403,t:lowercase,msg:'Don't use Proxy'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like

```
<LocationMatch "wp-comments-post.php" >
    SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "@gt 0" "log,deny,id:48,status:403,msg:'Don't use Proxy'"
</LocationMatch>
```

I haven't got a machine handy to test this on but it ought to deny access to the relevant location if there are >0 X-Forward-For request headers. Lots of companies use proxies so you may find that you need to make this "@gt 1" to reduce false positives. The apache [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) and [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this if you enclose the modsec rules inside a location directive 
eg.

```
<Location /koko/lala/wp-comments-post.php >
SecRule .... 
</Location>
```